# What can i use for a Mac to limit each computer session to 15 minutes?

Tags: mac, timer

I had a software for my PC that was a parental control program, with the ability to set a limit on how long each user was on at a sitting, and I limited myself to 15 minutes at a time, with a 15 minute break before being able to get on again. Is there a way to use Mac's built-in timers to do this, or a software that will?

Comment: How do you ever get anything done like that? 15/15 seems awfully harsh!

Answer (score 6):

Parental Controls in System Preferences will be perfect. Here is an image of the preference pane:

[image: Parental controls preference pane]